# Group tuple according to date in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, tuples

```
[(-0.0625, u'2017-02-14'), (0.21428571428571427, u'2017-02-14'), (0.125, u'2017-02-14')]
```

I have list of tuples which looks like this. I'm trying to get the average of the decimals according to each month of the year.

What is the fastest(in terms of speed) pythonic way to do something like this ?

Comment: Fastest in terms of speed or line count?

Comment: Also, that's a list of tuples, not a tuple.

Comment: `sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda tuple: tuple[1])`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yeah thats what i meant. Fixed it. Fastest in terms of speed

Comment: @erip wont that filter according to the date ? Im trying to filter according to each month of the year

Comment: It will sort by date. You can then do your averages easily since the list will be sorted lexicographically. This will be O(n log n) instead of worst-case brute force O(n^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another month, and here is what you can do without external libraries:

```
a = [(-0.0625, u'2017-02-14'), (0.21428571428571427, u'2017-02-14'), (0.125, u'2017-02-14'), (-0.1625, u'2017-03-14'), (0.21428571428571427, u'2017-03-14'), (0.125, u'2017-03-14')]

months = list(set(['-'.join(item[1].split('-')[:2]) for item in a]))

grouped_data = [[x[0] for x in a if '-'.join(x[1].split('-')[:2]) == month] for month in months]

result = {month: sum(item)/len(item) for month, item in zip(months, grouped_data)}
```

Comment: It successfully aggregates according to the month. But it doesn't distinguish between different years. I was looking for a solution which filters according to different years too

Comment: And now it does :)

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are generally pretty fast. You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). This requires the list to be sorted by date (or at least by month), which you can do in-place:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import date
from calendar import month_name # This is just to pretty-print the month

# This can be a lambda if you prefer
def get_month(x):
    return date.strptime(x[1], "%Y-%m-%d").month

l = [(-0.0625, u'2017-02-14'), (0.21428571428571427, u'2017-02-14'), (0.125, u'2017-02-14')].sort(key=get_month)
for mon, group in groupby(l, get_month)
    group = [x[0] for x in group]
    mean = sum(group) / len(group)
    print('Sum for month {}: {}'.format(month_name[mon], mean))
```

There are a number of ways to extract the month, and `strptime` is probably not the fastest, but it is the safest and most flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to create a DataFrame, resample to monthly and calculate the mean of each month:

```
import pandas as pd
l = [(-0.0625, u'2017-02-14'), 
     (0.21428571428571427, u'2017-02-14'), 
     (0.125, u'2017-02-14')]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['value','date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date')
print df.resample('M').mean()
```